# dynamically change an element's class name and have it immediately change the page's appearance

Tags: javascript, css

How do I dynamically change an element's class name and have it **immediately** change the page's appearance

Before I present the code snippets, **the problem is** that the section with id="shutterWrapper" stays hidden and the section with id="noshutterWrapper" stays visible.

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

window.onload = function() {

    var element;

    element = document.getElementById("shutterWrapper");
    element.class = "show";

    element = document.getElementById("noshutterWrapper");
    element.class = "hide";

}

-->
</script>

</head>

<body>

<section id="shutterWrapper" class="hide">

</section>

<section id="noshutterWrapper" class="show">

</section>
```

with this in my .css file:

```
.show {
    display: block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `element.class`, but what you want is `element.className`. Try using that in your code instead!

[From MDN's entry on className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className):

> `className` gets and sets the value of the class attribute of the specified element.

Here is an example of your code that should work:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var element;

    element = document.getElementById("shutterWrapper");
    element.className = "show";

    element = document.getElementById("noshutterWrapper");
    element.className = "hide";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

your javascript is slightly off. Instead of using `element.class` you need to use `element.className`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

window.onload = function() {

    var element;

    element = document.getElementById("shutterWrapper");
    element.className = "show";

    element = document.getElementById("noshutterWrapper");
    element.className = "hide";

}

-->
</script>
```

Should do the trick!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

Answer (score 0):

The entire "class" attribute has the JavaScript property [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) (not `class`), and in newer browsers, you can manipulate specific entries using the more convenient [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property.

In newer browsers:

```
 var setVisible = function(element, isVisible) {
    if (isVisible) {
       element.classList.remove('hidden');
     } else {
       element.classList.add('hidden');
     }
  };
```

In older browsers:

```
 var setVisible = function(element, isVisible) {
    var classNameWithoutHidden =
       element.className.replace(/hidden\s+/, '');
    if (isVisible) {
       element.className = classNameWithoutHidden + ' hidden';
     } else {
       element.className = classNameWithoutHiden;
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered something, namely:

```
element.setAttribute("class", "show");   // or, element.className = "show"
```

Now, thanks to all of you, the problem was **99% solved** ... the last remaining glitch **was** a **split second flicker** as described in the following.

In the body, I assume JS is turned **off** and put in the body a **showing** id = noshutterWrapper and a **hidden** id = shutterWrapper.  I have the `<script>` above that has **window.onload** wherein I swap the two with hiding id = noshutterwrapper and showing id = shutterWrapper.

The body loads and the id = noshutterWrapper is shown for a split second, followed by it being hidden and the id = shutterWrapper is shown because JS is enabled.

This split second flicker of a shown noshutterWrapper was solved via:

$(document).ready (function() { ... })

rather than window.onload = function() { ... }

Flicker gone and I can put this `<script>` in the `<header>` where it belongs.

**Problem 100% solved!**